# Making div contained in container div

Tags: css

What `CSS` properties makes `a`,`b`,`div` contained by the container ?

http://jsfiddle.net/01d244jm/

```
div {
 border: 1px solid green;    
}

#container {
 position: fixed;   
 width: 100%;
}

.a, .b {
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
<div id="container">
    <div class="a">abc</div>
    <div class="b">efg</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

position: fixed, and position: absolute are legacy part, and I think they are logical : I want to put a, b into fixed container relatively. Why should I change absolute to relative ?

It can not be solved without changing a,b position to relative ? Why ? And why I need to change the container height ? a,b are in container

Comment: Why are you positioning your elements absolutely?

Comment: position: fixed, and position: absolute are legacy part, and I think they are logical : I want to put a, b into fixed container relatively. Why should I change absolute to relative ?

Comment: It can not be solved without changing a,b position to relative ? Why ? And why I need to change the container height ? a,b are in container

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the absolute positioning from the div `a` and `b`

[Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/01d244jm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
position: absolute;
```

to

```
 position: relative;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.a, .b {
    width : 20%;
    float : left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child elements are indeed positioned within the parent block.

However, because there is no inflow content within `#container`, its height collapses to zero, to is appears that the child elements are not within it.

If you specify a height to the parent block, you see that `.a` and `.b` are positioned within it, as you expected.

In your original example, the child elements were overflowing outside of the parent container (that had zero height).  If you had set `overflow: hidden` on the parent, the child elements would not have been visible.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#container {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
}
.a,.b {
  position: absolute;
}
.a {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
.b {
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="a">abc</div>
  <div class="b">efg</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want but if it's just to have a and b divs in a bigger container with some border, just do like this:

css:

```
#container {
     position: fixed;   
     border: 1px solid green; 
}

.a {
    margin:10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="a">abc</div>
    <div classput="a">efg</div>
</div>
```